# case class with scalaz.NonEmptyList[A] as member and the ===, equals, ==

Tags: scala, equals, scalaz

I want to compare case classes with the scalaz `NonEmptyList` field. The `==` or `euqls` doesn't work, and I know that this is becouse of `NonEmptyList.equals` method which checks if compared object is the same instance as caller. On the other hand the scalaz `===` function works fine for `NonEmptyList` provided there must be implicit `Equals` in scope.

The problem is that I want to make my case class generic and want to instances of this to be easily comparable.

How to do this?

If the only solution is providing custom `def equals(obj: Any): Boolean` method, please to post it below.

My code:

```
object Problem {

  case class CC[M, N](s: M, nel: NonEmptyList[N])

  CC(1, 2.wrapNel) == CC(1, 2.wrapNel) //false

  CC(1, 2.wrapNel) equals CC(1, 2.wrapNel) //false


  implicit def cCEquals[M, N] = equalA[CC[M, N]]

  CC(1, 2.wrapNel) === CC(1, 2.wrapNel) //false

  //override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = ???
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it probably doesn't help you, but the `equals` method on `NonEmptyList` works as expected in Scalaz 7. (Edit: Actually this is [now fixed in Scalaz 6](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/commit/5a6e6080) as well, so if you're willing to build from source or wait for 6.0.5, you'll be fine anyway.)

There's still a natural way to solve this problem with `Equal` in Scalaz 6.0.4 or earlier, though—you just have to make sure you're building the right `Equal` instance for `CC[M, N]`:

```
implicit def ccEqual[M: Equal, N: Equal] =
  Equal.equalBy[CC[M, N], (M, NonEmptyList[N])] {
    case CC(s, nel) => (s, nel)
  }
```

Here we require that both `M` and `N` have `Equal` instances. The compiler can then build an `Equal` instance for `NonEmptyList[N]` and then for `(M, NonEmptyList[N])`. And there's an obvious mapping from `CC[M, N]` to `(M, NonEmptyList[N])`, which we can turn into the desired instance with `Equal.equalBy`.

If you're willing to use universal equality for `M` and `N`, you can do this instead:

```
implicit def ccEqual[M, N] = new Equal[CC[M, N]] {
  def equal(a: CC[M, N], b: CC[M, N]) =
    a.s == b.s && Equal.NonEmptyListEqual(Equal.equalA[N]).equal(a.nel, b.nel)
}
```

Or even just:

```
implicit def ccEqual[M, N] = new Equal[CC[M, N]] {
  def equal(a: CC[M, N], b: CC[M, N]) = a.s == b.s && a.nel.list == b.nel.list
}
```

With a little type-level magic (e.g. via Scalaz 7's `typelevel` or more easily with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)), you could have the compiler generate `Equal` instances for any case class with `Equal` instances for its members, but it's not too hard to write them out yourself.